# Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at about:blank sometimes occurs at the beginning of a Playwright test

Tags: playwright

I have a sequence of Playwright tests (using `test.describe.serial`) that test the checkout of an eCommerce application. They use the website to check out products, then check in the backoffice that the order is visible and then that the order is visible on the website in the order history. The error occurs from time to time (so far only locally) when starting the Order History page test. If I repeat only this test, it will always work the second time. What could be the reason?

```js
    test('Verify the Order History page', async ({ baseURL }) => {
        await loginPage.goto(`${baseURL}/${country}-en/`)
        await loginPage.login(contactDetails.email, password, `${contactDetails.firstName} ${contactDetails.lastName}`)
        await orderHistoryPage.goto(baseURL, country)
        await commonFunctions.verifyContactBoxInCart(contactBoxInCart)
        if (orderNumber) {
            await orderHistoryPage.findOrdersInOrderHistory(orderNumber)
        }
    })
```

Playwright says:

> Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at about:blank
>
> ```
> =========================== logs ===========================
> navigating to "about:blank", waiting until "load"
> ============================================================
> ```

I ran the tests and expected them to pass. Instead the Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at about:blank error occurred.

Comment: Please share the all relevant code  including config and common functions along with full stacktrace.